# Knapsack with weight swaps

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have a problem that is 0/1 knapsack, but you are also able to swap the weight of 2 items up to k times. I came up with a O(n*k*c) solution, but I am looking for a faster o(n*c) solution. I think the intuition is we should use all k swaps unless we can use less than k swaps and use all of the max values with the minimum weights. I just need help on the using all k swaps part

Comment: What is c?  Please define all notation.  Can you show us your $O(nkc)$ time algorithm?  Please proof-read your post -- the typesetting in $O(n*k*c)$ didn't work out the way you intended, due to Markdown.